Are questions about whether documentations use correct terms on-topic?
During programing, I come up with this kind of question:

I'm using lib A to solve problem B. The way its documentation uses the terms seems to be inconsistent and contradiction. Here is an example:
Some code

Even though it works, the variable is named after concept X. But isn't that it should be Y? If not, then why does [this other source] says otherwise?

While it does contain code, it's just an example and the question is still about the terms used in problem B. The language, lib, code or documentation isn't important, but just a way to lead me to the question. It isn't about "what does this concept mean?", but rather "is my understanding about this concept correct? And if yes, then is it correct that the code/documentation uses incorrect terms?". I guess it an on-topic question?
The article What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center - Computer Science Stack Exchange doesn't explicitly discuss about this.

It is unclear to me what this kind of question would be about. concept X/Y? problem B? I don't think "Is the documentation inconsistent?" is automatically on-topic, although it might be if concept X or problem B are on-topic.

Yeah, I think the question can be rewritten as about the concepts/problems, with confusing/contradictory usage from a specific docs of a lib

I don't think we can tell whether the variable should be named after concept A or concept B without digging into the details of the code, and I think digging into the details of the code is likely beyond the scope of this site.
I suggest that you try to figure out what is preventing you from answering that question yourself.  If the issue is that you don't understand the details of what the code is doing, then it's probably out-of-scope here.  If the issue is that you don't understand the definition of concept A, then I think you could ask a question about some specific aspect of concept A that you're unsure about, without reference to any code.
If the code isn't important, then presumably you should be able to omit the code and still ask a concrete, specific, clear question.
Our mission is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others, so I encourage you to think about how to formulate the question in a way that will be useful to others as well as to you.
If you're asking about naming, you might also put some thought into why you care about the answer.  Why does it matter what name is applied?  If the answer is that you want to understand the concept, and after reading the code you have a suspicion that you might not understand the concept, then maybe you can use the code to help you identify some specific aspect of the concept that you're unsure about, and ask about that.

Yes, I'm still learning the concepts, so my questions are ultimately to understand them. But in this case it isn't about "what does the concept mean?", but rather "is my understanding about the concept correct? And if yes, then is it correct that the code/documentation uses incorrect terms?". Is it an on-topic question?

@Ooker, Yes-or-no questions usually aren't an ideal fit for the goals of this site, as the answer is only "yes" or "no", which is unlikely to help future visitors -- and future visitors are unlikely to have exactly the same question.  "Does the code use incorrect terms?" is probably off-topic here, as coding questions are off-topic.
